# How to write concise code for the conditional creation (if…then…) of a set of global macro variables

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, sas-macro

I've created 14 global macro variables like so:

```
data _NULL_;
set &medf;
if &class1='Catcher' then call symputx('MedianC',med);
if &class1='Catcher' then call symputx('FrequencyC',_FREQ_);
if &class1='First Baseman' then call symputx('MedianFB',med);
if &class1='First Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencyFB',_FREQ_);
if &class1='Outfielder' then call symputx('MedianO',med);
if &class1='Outfielder' then call symputx('FrequencyO',_FREQ_);
if &class1='Pitcher' then call symputx('MedianP',med);
if &class1='Pitcher' then call symputx('FrequencyP',_FREQ_);
if &class1='Second Baseman' then call symputx('MedianSB',med);
if &class1='Second Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencySB',_FREQ_);
if &class1='Shortstop' then call symputx('MedianS',med);
if &class1='Shortstop' then call symputx('FrequencyS',_FREQ_);
if &class1='Third Baseman' then call symputx('MedianTB',med);
if &class1='Third Baseman' then call symputx('FrequencyTB',_FREQ_);
run;
```

This seems like an inefficient code, and so I was wondering how I might be able to write this more concisely. I've looked around at the various uses of `CALL SYMPUTX`, and it seems like I might not need 14 lines of code for 14 global macro variables (i.e., a single line of `CALL SYMPUTX` might be able to produce multiple macro variables). However, I'm not sure how to retain the conditional nature of my variable creation in fewer lines of code.

If anyone could offer some guidance, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: Why are you creating macro variables with those values?  As I think I commented on your other question, probably the answer is _don't use macro variables_ and use a dataset that you merge on (or do something else) instead.  Or create a format.  Or use a hash table.  Lots of ways to get data from one place to another in SAS - macro variables are one of the _worst_.

Comment: @Joe  Would you mind explaining why macro variables aren't ideal in this case (or providing a relevant link)?  For now, I'm only using them to learn how to code macros in SAS, but it would great to know more about the pitfalls of macro variables for future reference.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on your previous question, I agree with Joe. Use a macro for this problem is using a sledgehammer for a tack.  A much simpler method is a good proc means with a merge.

Comment: It's not a brief explanation, but the basic concept is that if you're a programmer from another language, macro variables "feel" like that other language often - but they're not. They're tools for doing certain things, but the data step language is far more powerful.  Data step language is like using objects in C++ - macro language is like just using base-type variables in C++ with no classes or objects.

Comment: @Joe So it's mostly that there are much more efficient/powerful methods that could more easily address this problem?

Comment: I would generally recommend that someone new to SAS not learn the macro language *at all*, and learn how to do everything using base SAS, until they're very comfortable with the data step language and the procs.  So much is possible in the data step language that learning the macro language first leads to not learning the data step language sufficiently, and that's ultimately a bad sign.

Comment: @Joe I've learned a good amount of base SAS, but yes, you're right--I could definitely take time to learn it better.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mrt Yes, you can think of it that way.  I'd go so far as to say that the above method is _wrong_, in that I would reject code like that during a code review, because it's impossible to maintain and update, and impossible to be confident that you aren't doing something wrong.

Comment: @Joe  Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the first letter of each `&class1` 'word' can form a suffix to place at the end of the macro variable name, you can complete this task without any need for `if-then` logic:

```
data _NULL_;
set &medf;
length suff $8;
i=1;
/* Do loop pulls together the first letter of each word */
/* in the &class1 variable value into a new variable called suff */
do while (scan(&class1,i) ^= '');
  suff=cats(suff,substr(scan(&class1,i),1,1));
  i+1;
end;

/* The Median and Frequency words joined to suff make the new macro variable name, */ 
/* the second argument just holds the values */
call symputx(cats('Median',suff),med);
call symputx(cats('Frequency',suff),_FREQ_);

run;
```

Comment: I would recommend you follow the advice of the commenters, particularly Joe. This answers your question, but as he says, your approach may need reviewing.